# Bypassing the browser cache by asp-append-version not working in iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, tag-helpers

I have used the `asp-append-version="true"` for bypassing the browser cache but it's not working when I use it in an `iframe`.

Do I have to change my solution?

Comment: Are you using the asp-append-version on the iFrame itself or on a script/image element inside of it? I ask because the iFrame element doesn't support that attribute.

Comment: I used it in scripts and images element inside of an iFrame.

Comment: Sounds like the browser is caching the entire iFrame. I'd try appending the current date time to the iFrame's URL to break that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Lifting my answer from my comment above)

The browser is caching the entire iframe. If you append say the current date time to the iframe's URL it'll break the cache.